# Laravel - update database to fit array

Tags: php, ajax, database, laravel

I have table 'categories', with fields: id, parent_id, name, order. Parent_id is foreign key to other category's id. Now my controller receives array from ajax request:

```
public function saveCategories(Request $request) {
    if(!$request->ajax()) return Response::json(['error' => 'Received data has invalid format'], 500);

    $data = $request->all()['data'];
    return $data;
}
```

Array received has the very same fields as table, so:
id, parent_id, name and order.

What is the most convenient way to update table 'categories' with given array? What has to be kept in mind:

1. Elements with same ID as ones in array just get updated.
2. New elements, so ones that 'id' is not yet found in database, are to be added.
3. Elements that are not found but occur in database have to be deleted.

Do I have to loop through all elements and modify database manually?

E: Some of other tables refers to categories, so solution of removing every row and creating all records from scratch is not an option.

E2: Inspired by @EduardoJunior answer, I've managed to do the following:

```
public function saveCategories(Request $request) {
  if(!$request->ajax()) return Response::json(['error' => 'Sent data invalid format'], 500);

  $data = $request->all()['data'];
  $all_ids = array_map(function($category){

  Category::updateOrCreate(['id' => $category['id']], ['name' => $category['name'],
    'parent_id' => $category['parent_id'], 'order' => $category['order']]);
  return $category['id'];

    }, $data);

  Category::whereNotIn('id', $all_ids)->delete();
  return ['success' => true];
}
```

*It creates and modifies rows, but only changing/adding name field. Parent_id remains unchanged or gets default null in new rows, same with order field.
If I removed one category, so Category::whereNotIn() is to be fired, server throws error 500.*

E3: Of course it was problem with $fillable, I feel so stupid. Also removing is working now. However, 'parent_id' => $category['parent_id'] in updateOrCreate() is still not working. Name and order and saved correctly, but this field not.

Comment: What database are you using? in mysql there is `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`, searching for upsert + db name will get you on the right track.

Comment: If the array has the same attributes as the table has and all of them are `fillable` in the model. you could do something like Category::insert($request->all()['data']);

Comment: @EduardoJunior but will it update existing rows and delete ones that did not occured?

Comment: @TheRuthlessHacker i apologize, didn't read rightly the question. I'll post an answer for you.

Comment: What is the text of the 500 you are receiving ? Doesn't it show to you the exception dump?

Comment: Are the `parent_id` and `order` fields, inside the `$fillable` array in the Category model ?

Comment: They were not. The very last problem comes with parent_id field, I've described it E3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Eduardo Junior I was able to resolve the problem:

```
$data = $request->all()['data'];

$all_ids = array_map(function($category){

  Category::updateOrCreate(['id' => $category['id']], ['name' => $category['name'],
    'order' => $category['order']]);
  return $category['id'];

}, $data);
Category::whereNotIn('id', $all_ids)->delete();

foreach($data as $category) {
  $child = Category::find($category['id']);
  $child->parent()->associate(Category::find($category['parent_id']));
  $child->save();
}
```

Note: parent_id update is made with Eloquent associate method, after all new categories are created to avoid any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You could do just like this:

```
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {

        //Upsert all items, and store their ids to delete the ones that are not present.
        $all_ids = array_map(function($category){

            DB::statement(' INSERT INTO categories (id, parent_id, name, order)'.
                        ' VALUES ('.$category['id'].','.$category['parent_id'].','.$category['name'].','.$category['order'].')'.
                        ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE parent_id='.$category['id'].','.
                                                'name='.$category['name'].','.
                                                'order='.$category['order']);

            return $category['id'];

        }, $data = $request->all()['data']);

    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        throw $e;
    }

    Category::whereNotIn('id', $all_ids)->delete();

    DB::commit();
```

- Added a transaction handling there for performance reasons and to maintain the database consistency if some exception is thrown.
- I didn't test it, but i think it could direct you on the right way. :)

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to edit a little bit your code as it was returning error 500 (I belive in line with DB::satement method). But some problems still do occur, I've described it in E2 in orginal post

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it

```
 /// delete not in list
    Category::whereNotIn($data->pluck('id'))->delete();

    /// add or update array
    foreach($data as $row){ 
        Category::updateOrCreate(
            [$row['id']], /// id of model
            [$row] /// model array
        );
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... strangely Category::whereNotIn($data->pluck('id'))->delete() is causing error 500.

Comment: @TheRuthlessHacker If you want to use this approach, you should transform your array in a collection before. With collect($data), Something like `$data = collect($data)`. 

*When you receive a 500 error. Give us the text of it : )